# ¿Como sumar los resultados de una consulta SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con pedidos de frutas y verduras:

```
pedidos (nombre, fecha, total, tipo_de_producto)
```

Quiero separar por mes lo que se vendio de fruta y lo que se vendio de verdura. Es decir obtener 4 columnas mes, año, ganancias frutas, ganancias verduras. Hasta el momento obtengo la suma total asi:

```
SELECT Month(fecha) as mes, YEAR(fecha) AS año,
SUM(total) as ganancias
FROM pedidos    
group by 
YEAR(`fecha`),
Month(`fecha`)
order by Año
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Saludos. Pues la consulta ya la tienes, solo te falta agregar (por lo que entendí) `tipo_de_producto` entre el `select` y `from` como en el `group by`. Ahora bien ¿tu duda al respecto en que consiste? Si hay algún error o resultado erróneo favor de indicar en que consiste.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr, tu comentario está excelente como respuesta. Por qué no contestas con el código completo?

Comment: @RobertoLeOr solo toma en cuenta que el OP menciona que desea los resultados en columnas diferentes, por lo que requiere un poco más que solo añadir el `tipo_de_producto`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, como indica @JosueArriola necesito los resultados en columnas diferentes. Gracias!

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. @Patricio deseable coloques (así sea una imagen) del resultado esperado; es decir la salida de que forma esperas recibirla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puedes lograr lo que necesitas haciendo un pivot, aunque en MySQL (que yo sepa) no existe esa sentencia como en SQL Server, puedes intentar algo así, donde la subconsulta haría las veces de pivot y la condición haría la "magia":

```
SELECT 
año,
mes,
sums.Frutas, 
sums.Verduras
FROM (
SELECT
Month(fecha) as mes, 
YEAR(fecha) AS año,
SUM(IF(tipo_de_producto='fruta',total,0) ) As 'Frutas',
SUM(IF(tipo_de_producto='verdura',total,0) ) As 'Verduras'
FROM pedidos
GROUP BY 
Month(fecha), 
YEAR(fecha)
) AS sums;
```

Te adjunto el ejemplo funcionando con los datos que ingrese:

<kbd>[Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8186b5799ecf971c583e08743b88ac05)</kbd>

En este link puedes obtener más información.

<kbd>[Más información](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78)</kbd>

Ojala sea lo que buscas. Saludos.